# interactions with counters and file i/o

Tags: c, io, overflow

I have a program that is supposed to count the number of times a letter appears in a text file.

```
void file_histogram(char *filename)
{
  FILE *file1;
    file1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    int size = 26;
    int charCounters[size];
    char c;
    int i, j;

    if(file1 != NULL) {
        while(fscanf(file1, "%c", &c) == 1) {
            for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                if(c == i + 97) {
                    charCounters[i]++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        printf("%c: %d\n", j + 97, charCounters[j]);
    fclose(file1);
```

what this seems to be doing is counting the first character twice, and then about half are correctly counted, and the other half all seemed to reach the max or overflow. what exactly is going on here?

Comment: How are you determining that int size = 26? And is this supposed to be for a particular "known" file or any file?

Comment: a) You never set charCounters to all 0. b) why do you even have a for loop in that file reading section?

Comment: the array is for each letter of the alphabet

Comment: the file will only contain lowercase letters. My idea was to go through for each letter and increment a counter.

Comment: that helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the logic of the first `for()` loop is not correct. suggest something like:

```
#include <ctype.h>
....
// initialize to all 0s
int charCounters[26] = {0};
....
while(fscanf(file1, "%c", &c) == 1) 
{
    if( isalpha(c) )
    {  // then alphabet a...z or A...Z
        // -'a' to get offset from lower case 'a'
        // to use as index into array
        charCounters[ tolower(c)-'a' ]++;
    }
}
```